# Service Broker only receiving one message at a time

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, service-broker

Even when I specify Receive Top(25), etc I am only getting one message to be dequeued at a time.  Not sure what i am doing wrong inside my sproc? Probably something trivial, but I don't see the problem.

Sproc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SPP_DEQUEUE_MESSAGE

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @receiveTable TABLE(
message_type        sysname,
message_body        xml,
message_dialog      uniqueidentifier);

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    WAITFOR
        ( RECEIVE TOP(25)
            message_type_name,
            message_body,
            conversation_handle  
          FROM TargetQueue1DB
            INTO @receiveTable
        ), TIMEOUT 3000;

    SELECT 
        *
    From @receiveTable;     

    Delete from @receiveTable;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END --End Sproc
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

B

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess would be that each message belongs to a different conversation (and therefore by default to a different conversation group). If this is the case, then this is expected behavior.

From [Books Online - Receive (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186963.aspx):

> All messages that are returned by a
>   RECEIVE statement belong the same
>   conversation group

If you want to receive multiple messages at once, send multiple messages on a single conversation or [group multiple conversations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174987.aspx) into a single conversation group on the receiving end.

Comment: Thanks Pawel I will take a look at that.  I didn't see that part...that is probably what is happening.

Comment: Could you please provide any example on this? We are sending messages from a table INSERT trigger, and therefore have to create a separate conversation for every INSERT. I'd like to receive all possible messages in a batch, but this does not happen and I don't see how to move conversations in a single group (even by using WITH RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP in BEGIN DIALOG)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how many messages are in that queue, before the proc is run?

If you run the following query to get the count in all your queues

SELECT sq.name,
    p.rows 
FROM sys.service_queues sq 
    Join sys.internal_tables it ON sq.object_id = it.parent_id 
        AND it.parent_minor_id = 0 
        AND it.internal_type = 201
    Join sys.indexes as i on i.object_id = it.object_id and i.index_id = 1 
    Join sys.partitions as p on p.object_id = i.object_id and p.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE 
    sq.object_id = it.parent_id AND 
    it.parent_minor_id = 0 AND 
    it.internal_type = 201

If there is more than 1 message in that queue, you should get more than 1 in your receive.

Comment: There is more than one message that is in the queue